Any %stopscript for cleaning up the service in Singularity def file?
It is known that %startscript section of a Singularity def file defines commands to run for a background service. Some service would allocate resources When starting, and there are other particular commands needed to clean up these resources when the service is stopped. So, I would like to add these clean-up commands to the Singularity def file which will be called when the user runs instance stop command. If I were the developer of Singularity, I would introduce a section named %stopscript in def file in correspondence with the %startscript section. But unfortunately, there is no such %stopscript section in Singularity. So, is there any way to run clean-up commands automatically when running "singularity instance stop" command, just like destructor of C++ class?
